# Evaluate an infinite series involving the polygamma function OR first derivative of the hurwitz zeta function

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, closed-form, polygamma

Can we find a closed form for
$$\sum _{k=1}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^k}{2k-1}\left(2k^2-k+8k^2P_1(k)-16kP_2(k)+16P_3(k)\right)$$
where
$$P_n(k)=\psi^{(-n)}\left(k+\frac12\right)-\psi^{(-n)}\left(k+1\right)$$

Here the definition for $\psi^{(-n)}(x)$ I'm using is
$$\psi^{(-n)}(x)=\frac{1}{\left(n-2\right)!}\int _0^x\left(x-t\right)^{n-2}\ln\Gamma(t)dt$$ for $n\gt1$
and $\psi^{(-1)}(x)=\ln\Gamma(x)$

The value of the sum is near $5.7971...$

I've tried to simplify the $P_n(k)$ hoping that there would be cancelling, but with no luck. Perhaps there is an asymptotic approach?

**EDIT**: I've simplified the sum to be in terms of the first derivative of the Hurwitz Zeta function.  So my sum is the same as

$$\frac{\pi}{4}(8\ln A+3\ln(2\pi))+\sum _{k=1}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^k}{2k-1}\left[8k^2\left(\zeta^{(1,0)}\left(0,k+\frac12\right)-\zeta^{(1,0)}\left(0,k+1\right)\right)-16k\left(\zeta^{(1,0)}\left(-1,k+\frac12\right)-\zeta^{(1,0)}\left(-1,k+1\right)\right)+8\left(\zeta^{(1,0)}\left(-2,k+\frac12\right)-\zeta^{(1,0)}\left(-2,k+1\right)\right)\right]$$
Where $A$ is the Glaisher-Kinkelin constant. Maybe we can try using [Perron's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula)?

Comment: At $n=1$, the integral diverges.

Comment: Personally, I'd have$$\psi^{(-n)}(x)=\frac1{(n-1)!}\int_1^x(x-t)^{n-1}\psi(t)~\mathrm dt$$

Comment: How'd you get $2.89855$?

Comment: Shouldn't that integral be from 0 to x?

Comment: Related: [Explicit forms of negapolygamma difference with arguments that differ by a half?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2406675/explicit-forms-of-negapolygamma-difference-with-arguments-that-differ-by-a-half)

Comment: Integrating over $0$, note that $\lim_{t\to0}t\psi(t)=-1$, so the integral diverges at $0$. (Indeed, we can't have $\log(\Gamma(x))-\log(\Gamma(0^+))$, as $\log(\Gamma(0^+))=-\infty$)

Comment: Also note the arbitrariness of the lower bound on the integral. So long as the integral converges, any lower bound is a suitable definition for $\psi^{(-n)}$, which is why one must specify such details.

Comment: Okay, but due to the confusion and because that integral definition didn't work for me I went back to my previous integral definition.

Comment: That's fine. As I said, all these definitions are valid.

Comment: Note that the summand is relatively monotone taking away the alternating signs. Thus, an Euler summation should quickly provide an approximation to the sum.

Comment: Which integral definition are you using, because the one you proposed wasn't giving me the right values... also try plugging in $8\ln A+3\ln(2\pi)$ ($A$ is the Glaisher-Kinkelin constant) into the summand and that accelerates the convergence.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo with the signs. And what does $8\ln A+3\ln(2\pi)$ have to do here O.o

Comment: Okay good.  You can disregard that if you want but it appears to be an ideal constant that increases the convergence speed.

Comment: I'd like to verify your claim that the sum is approximately $2.89855$. Do we agree that for $k=1$, we get $7.39277$? And for $k=2$, we get $-2.48115$? If so, then the series is bounded between $$7.39277-2.48115<S<7.39277$$And it would appear your result is wrong.

Comment: My bad, I had a half in my calculations that I totally just left in there.  You're right!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64509/discussion-between-user991003-and-simply-beautiful-art).

Comment: When providing such weird series you should give more context, like a good reason for looking at thisone in particular

Answer (score 1):

By Euler summing up to $0\le k\le p\le n\le15$, I found that

```
n    sum
---  ------------
0    3.6963863814
1    4.9242922276
2    5.4146695729
3    5.6246336957
4    5.7178928561
5    5.7602644696
6    5.7798140328
7    5.7889347699
8    5.7932259771
9    5.7952583022
10   5.7962259359
11   5.7966886603
12   5.7969107445
13   5.7970176641
14   5.7970692763
15   5.7970942481
```

Where I used

$$S_n=\sum_{p=0}^n\frac1{2^{p+1}}\sum_{k=0}^p\binom pka_{k-1}$$

where $a_k$ are your terms.